# Oracle SQL, using a sequence in a separate select query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to insert some data into a table from a select statement. I know I can do it like this:

```
insert into new_logs (idLog, logEntry)
(select idLog, logEntry from old_logs)
```

But, I am running into a problem when trying to execute this type of query when I need to pass in a sequence value:

```
insert into new_logs (idLog, logEntry)
(select LOGSEQ.NEXTVAL, logEntry from old_logs)
```

I think the problem is because the sequence comes from the dual table, but the query above implies that it comes from the old_logs table.

I also tried this,

```
insert into new_logs (idLog, logEntry)
select next_value for LOGSEQ, logEntry from old_logs
```

But I still can't get it to work. Could someone please tell me if what I am trying to do is possible? All I want to do is run an insert statement using a select query *and*
a sequence on another schema.

Comment: It's always helpful to specify what error you are getting rather than hoping that we can guess correctly.  Are you saying that `logseq` is a sequence that is owned by a user other than the one you are running the `INSERT` statement as?  Does your user have permission to use the sequence?  If so, you'd need a fully qualified object name unless you are creating synonyms for the sequence.

Comment: It should work. what error do you get. Sequence does not come from any table. It is an independent object.

Comment: The error said "sequence number not allowed here", but I rewrote the query from scratch and it worked. I guess what I typed here did not match what I was running, so I apologize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is correct, as shown below:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE old_logs AS
  2     SELECT ROWNUM idLog, 'a' logEntry FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;

Table created

SQL> CREATE TABLE new_logs AS
  2     SELECT * FROM old_logs WHERE 1 = 2;

Table created

SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE logseq;

Sequence created

SQL> INSERT INTO new_logs (idLog, logEntry)
  2  (SELECT LOGSEQ.NEXTVAL, logEntry FROM old_logs);

10 rows inserted
```

What error message exactly do you get?

Comment: I rec'd the following error: "sequence number not allowed here", but I decided to rewrite the query from scratch and it worked. I guess my syntax did not match what I typed here, I apologize

Answer (score 1):

your query 
insert into new_logs (idLog, logEntry)
(select LOGSEQ.NEXTVAL, logEntry from old_logs)  might give error if u have duplicate logentry field in old_logs.

try this:-

```
    insert into new_logs (idLog, logEntry)
select LOGSEQ.NEXTVAL, logEntry from (select distinct logEntry  from old_logs);
```